# Android save data with Service when activity dead

Tags: android, service, save

```
public class ReadList{
    private static SparseArray<Read> LIST = new SparseArray<>();

    public static void add(int ID){
         LIST.put(ID, new Read(ID, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())));
    }

    public static void remove(int ID){
        if(LIST.indexOfKey(ID) >= 0 )
            LIST.remove(ID);
    }
}
```

I have some similar readlist class.. Saving data with SharedPreference correctly and normally.

But i want when onDestroy(), onStop() or onPause() method called my **DataSaveService** starting and saving data SharedPreference file..

```
public class DataSaveService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        MyCustomSharedSaveData.saveAllReadListtoXML();
        MyCustomSharedSaveData.saveAllFavoriteListtoXML();
    }
}
```

***Is it possible?*** Thank you and sory for my bad english..

Comment: Yes it is possible - started services do not depend on bound clients unlike bound services. Just keep in mind two things: you have to stop the started Service after you've done what you wanted to (I think in your case it will have to call stopSelf method) and second: only onPause() of Activity is guaranteed to be called

Comment: can i give me example? I write service and when activity state onStop(), onDestroy() or onPause() then my service working correctly but doesnt save my data..

Answer (score 1):

`onDestroy()` call is up to the Android OS, as it calls it when the memory is getting low, so placing your service call there might not be a good idea. `onStop()` will be called when an activity is hidden completely from the view that is either user minimizes the app or a new activity is opened from the from the previous one, so i suppose you can call the sevice in **onStop** method

Comment: thankyou for answer i need the learn when activity dead i start service. service working normally but doesnt save my data correctly?        MyCustomSharedSaveData.saveAllReadListtoXML();MyCustomSharedSaveData.saveAllFavoriteListtoXML(); they methods outside the service. that's why you can?